# What's happening when I call a function with args separated with commas?

Tags: f#

Very much a newbie with F#, can't seem to get my googler to work for this question.

I have this function

```
namespace RiskMeasurement
module Basics01 =
    let AvailableCapital (nominalAssetValue: float) (provisions: float) (liabilities: float) =
        nominalAssetValue - provisions - liabilities
```

Called with

```
namespace RiskMeasurement
module Main =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        let floats = Array.map float args
        let availableCapital = Basics01.AvailableCapital floats.[0] floats.[1] floats.[2]
        printfn "Available Capital: %f" availableCapital

        let availableCapital = Basics01.AvailableCapital floats.[0], floats.[1], floats.[2]

        // Return 0 to indicate success.
        0
```

When I call the function with the args separated by spaces, availableCapital is a float. That makes sense. When called with commas separating the args, availableCapital is (float -> float -> float) * float * float. I don't get that at all. What am I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Basics01.AvailableCapital floats.[0], floats.[1], floats.[2]
```

is a 3-tuple containing `Basics01.AvailableCapital floats.[0]` as its first element `floats.[1]` as the second element and `floats.[2]` as the third element.

Answer (score 3):

Read it like this:

```
let availableCapital = (Basics01.AvailableCapital floats.[0]), floats.[1], floats.[2]
```

So the first component of `availableCapital` is a partially applied function that wants two more arguments.

If you wanted to call it with the arguments separated by commas, you would write

```
let availableCapital = Basics01.AvailableCapital (floats.[0], floats.[1], floats.[2])
```

and get a type error.

Answer (score 2):

Some other good answers already; briefly, the 'comma operator' has very low precedence when it comes to parsing expressions.

Since you mention you are new to F#, you might want to check out

[F# function types: fun with tuples and currying](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!169.entry)

if you need to learn about the difference between `f(x,y)` and `f x y`.